# How to calculate BMI in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a function to calculate BMI in python. The formula says bmi equals weight divided by the square of height.
This is my attempt to write the formula, however, it does not produce the correct result. Can someone point out what is wrong with my logic?

```
def bmi_calc(weight, height):
    result = weight / height ** height
    return result

print(bmi_calc(79, 1.83)) # Wrong answer!
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It returns 26.14 for those two *specific* inputs, sure, but I can get different numbers by picking random inputs easily.

Comment: It shouldn't output anything... You're not `print`ing anything... Also, when I pick random numbers, it returns different numbers... Is your issue that it's returning the wrong value, or returning the same values?

Comment: @kenntnisse If you're using the console (or Jupyter notebooks), you can get output without a `print`. Since the question says it outputs the "wrong" value (not that it's giving *no* output), I expect a lack of a `print` isn't the issue. But then it's not really clear what the issue is, since that code shouldn't produce the "same value regardless of inputs".

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen The original question said that the function produced the same output for all inputs, which is simply false. The edit claims that the function produces the "wrong bmi", which is not a programming question. This question should be edited to indicate, mathematically and in simple English, what a "correct" BMI calculation looks like. Because the function provided right now calculates width divided by height to its own power, and it does so flawlessly.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I agree with what you said, and how the question does not suit to stackoverflow guidelines. The thing is we understand what he is trying to say. He does not know what are the correct operators for multiplication and exponents. Rather than down-voting his question, edit it, and clarify that the question aims to implement the bmi formula in python, but fails to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented the BMI formula incorrectly.
In python `a**b` means a to the power of b not a multiplied by b.
It should be:

```
def bmi_calc(weight, height):
    result = weight / height ** 2
    return result

bmi_calc(79, 1.83)
```

Output:

```
23.589835468362743
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to square the height, but your code is taking the height to the power of height.
Therefore, the correct function would be:

```
def bmi_calc(weight, height):
    return (weight / (height * height))

print(bmi_calc(79, 1.83))
```

Comment: this is incorrect ```a/b*b``` is ```a```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Forgot to include braces around height * height.

Answer (score -2):

def bmi_calc(weight, height):
result = weight / height ** height
return result

print(bmi_calc(79, 1.83))  <-- You forgot the print statement